# How to rewrite Swift ++ operator in ?: ternary operator

Tags: swift, swift2

I have the following code

```
var column = 0

column = column >= 2 ? 0 : ++column
```

Since 2.2 I get a depreciation warning, any ideas how I can fix this?

I have this solution:

```
if column >= 2 {
    column = 0
} else {
    column += 1
}
```

But this isn't really nice.

Comment: It is the original code that wasn't nice. `column = ++column` is a dreadful thing to say. This is exactly why the operator is being abolished.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about:

```
column = (column >= 2) ? 0 : column+1
```

It looks like you might be doing something like clock arithmetic.  If so, this gets the point across better:

```
column = (column + 1) % 2
```

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, you can replace `++column` with `column + 1`:

```
var column = 0
column = column >= 2 ? 0 : column + 1
```

---

You can also rewrite your code in an *if-else statement* with a `+=` operator:

```
var column = 0
if column >= 2 {
    column = 0
} else {
    column += 1
}
```

---

Moreover, **although I would not recommend using it in production code**, you can reimplement `++` (prefix / postfix increment operator) and `--` (prefix / postfix decrement operator) for type `Int` in Swift 2.2 and Swift 3 with [custom operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-ID46), [in-out parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545) and [defer statement](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/defer-statement).

```
// Swift 2.2

prefix operator ++ {}
prefix operator -- {}
postfix operator ++ {}
postfix operator -- {}

prefix func ++(inout a: Int) -> Int {
    a += 1
    return a
}

prefix func --(inout a: Int) -> Int {
    a -= 1
    return a
}

postfix func ++(inout a: Int) -> Int {
    defer { a += 1 }
    return a
}

postfix func --(inout a: Int) -> Int {
    defer { a -= 1 }
    return a
}
```

```
// Swift 3

prefix operator ++
prefix operator --
postfix operator ++
postfix operator --

@discardableResult prefix func ++( a: inout Int) -> Int {
    a += 1
    return a
}

@discardableResult prefix func --( a: inout Int) -> Int {
    a -= 1
    return a
}

@discardableResult postfix func ++( a: inout Int) -> Int {
    defer { a += 1 }
    return a
}

@discardableResult postfix func --( a: inout Int) -> Int {
    defer { a -= 1 }
    return a
}
```

As an example, the following playground code that uses ternary operator generates no warnings with Swift 2.2 and Swift 3:

```
var a = 10
print(a++) // prints 10
print(a) // prints 11

var b = 10
print(--b) // prints 9
print(b) // prints 9

var column = 0
column = column >= 2 ? 0 : ++column
print(column) // prints 1
```

Comment: This answer needs a big "Don't do it in real projects" disclaimer.

Comment: Apart from ugly cases such as `column = ++column`, is there any particular reason why it is not recommended ?